# Dynamically creation of index for access of object propery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties, dynamically-generated

I want to be able to dynamically build an index so I can iterate through the objects properties with buttons. Below is what I've tried with, which doesn't work. How could this be achieved?

```
var bodyNr = 3;
var theBody = {
    bodies: {
        1: null,
        2: null,
        3: null
    }
};
moveLeftBtn.on('click', function () {
    bodyNr -= 1;

    console.log(theBody.bodies["'" + bodyNr + "'"]); // undefined
    console.log(theBody.bodies['2']); // works
});
```

Comment: FWIW, if you need indices, why don't you want theBody.bodies to be an array?  Properties and indices are different and should not be thought of as the same thing, even what you've written works.  I'm not scolding, just making a suggestion.

Comment: Good point, changed it to an array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the apostrophies.

```
theBody.bodies[bodyNr]
```

Should work.

Comment: Damn, I tried it earlier without success and now when I've done some other changes and tried this it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

can't you just use `bodyNr` as an integer?

`theBody.bodies[bodyNr] // null`

additionally integers have a `toString` method

`bodyNr.toString()`